# Promise middleware in node js callback functions how to use multiple then?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, middleware

Am a newby in node js, Am using [Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) middleware in node js.
But I didn't find its documentation useful for me and unable to understand how to use two callbacks in one request or how should use multiple then.
Please help me thanks.

**Here is my code**

```
//get application types
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("in p1");
  var url = tURL+'applicationType/getAll'
  var args = {
    headers:{"AuthKey": req.session.name}
  };
  client.get(url, args, function(data,response) {
      console.log(data, "in get all app type req");
      if(data.status == "success"){
        return resolve(data);
      }
      else{
        reject ("unamble to get data!")
      }
  });
});

p1.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.response.applicationType, "in p1 then", data)
  //load page after data
  res.render('app', {
    message: req.session.name,
    uName: "THE MECHANIC",
    applist: data.response.applicationType
  });
},function(reason) {
  console.log(reason, "reason in not then"); // Error!
});



//get all application
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  console.log("in p2");
  var url = tURL+'applications'
  var args = {
    headers:{"AuthKey": req.session.name}
  };
  client.get(url, args, function(data,response) {
      console.log(data, "in get app req");
      if(data.status == "success"){
        return resolve(data);
      }
      else{
        reject ("unamble to get data!")
      }
  });
});

p2.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.response, "in p2 then", data)
  //load page after data
  res.render('app', {
    appList: data.response
  });

},function(reason) {
  console.log(reason, "reason in not p2"); // Error!
});
```

**Solutions am looking for**
1. I have to send data on page after both request complete.
2. How can I manage response in object and send it to page by using `render` or any alternative?

Comment: Try to use `Promise.all()` to check multiple promises being resolved.

Comment: @Sonaryr how to use it in my case could you please explain?

Comment: something like `Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(function(res){...});` check https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise#promise-all-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my first advice would be to find a way to promisify `client.get` in a native fashion, I am not sure what lib it represent, and it is not following node-style callback as `fun(err, data)`, that aside, I am assuming, you have a single request to your server, you carry multiple requests to something else, then bundle up all their responses and respond to the requester right?

I would restructure the code like

```
function pGet(url, args){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    client.get(url, args, function(data, response){
      if(data.status === 'success') resolve(data);
      else reject('unable to get data');
    });
  });
}

router.get('/api/someAPI', function(req, res, next){
  var resultJSON = {
    message: req.session.name,
    uName: "THE MECHANIC"
  }, args = { headers:{"AuthKey": req.session.name} },
  p1, p2;

  p1 = pGet(tURL+'applicationType/getAll', args)
    .then(function(data){
      resultJSON.applist = data.response.applicationType;
    }).catch(console.log.bind(console));

  p2 = pGet(tURL+'applications', args)
    .then(function(data){
      resultJSON.appList = data.response;
    }).catch(console.log.bind(console));

  // now we send the response once both of the promises finish
  Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function(){
    res.render('app', resultJSON); 
  }); // not adding any error handler since both the previous ones should not throw any.

});
```

Comment: callback(jsonData, res);
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I do not see any `callback`, can you update your question with the code

Comment: what `pget` function does in your snippet? how to call it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88343/discussion-between-the-mechanic-and-mido22).